# Why object is not initializing in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

Example: User.java

```
@Component
    public class User{
        public String name;
        public String email;



        public User() {
            super();
        }
        public User(String name, String email) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }



    }
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Resource
    User user;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getUsers", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(User user){
        return user;
    }
}
```

But user.getName() and user.getEmail() is null. User class is not initializing. Why? Even though I am sending user object at client side as

```
POST /spring/getUsers HTTP/1.1 Host: localhost:2015 Cache-Control: no-cache {"name":"vinod", "email":"vinod@gmaol.com" }
```

Comment: Do you realize you're returning the user passed as argument to the method, and not the autowired user, which is completely useless? Also, if the user is in the request body, as JSON, the argument is supposed to be annotated with `@RequestBody`

Comment: You might have to go through basics of how autowiring works and Model attributes etc.

Comment: Please give example to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code. Please go through the documentation once to understand how requestBody annotation works etc.

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/getUsers", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return user;
    }
}
```